# Which comment format is correct for TypeScript with annotations?

Tags: javascript, typescript, comments, jsdoc

I've been searching for an example of commenting on code that is annotated, all I can find are examples of comments on non annotated code.
Can anyone clarify the correct or approved standard way of writing this?

```
/**
 * Description.
 */
@Component({...})
class MyClass{...}
```

Or would this be written as

```
@Component({...})
/**
 * Description.
 */
class MyClass{...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CompoDoc has an [example](https://compodoc.app/guides/jsdoc-tags.html) of them using the first variation of the syntax you described. So, that means this (quoting their example) :

```js
/**
 * @ignore
 */
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

However as shows [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/tsdoc/issues/130), there's currently no fixed or official specification on how to write your TSDoc.

Comment: Dousse Thank you for the linked example. Greatly appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. I also added a link to an issue linked to TSDoc which is currently unsolved that might interest you.